# Is there an algorithm that finds the first occurence of any of the specified characters in a string?

Tags: c++, stl

I want something like this:

```
std::string str("123.15");
auto delimiterPos = str.find_any_of(",."); // delimiterPos == 3
```

Does STL have such an algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look up the `string` class in any reference and you'll find `find_first_of`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_first_of/

Comment: Thanks, I used `find_first_of` quite often and never realized it can accept strings and not just characters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it by calling

```
size_type pos = str.find_first_of(",.");
```